# How to properly call functions defined in other directories in Python?

Tags: python, module, python-import, subdirectory

Sorry, this has been already answered for sure, but I cannot find the answer to my problem... I want to make two separate scripts callable. Let me explain in detail with an example.

I have a directory structure similar to this:

```
maindir
|- subdir
|   |- script.py
|   `- myfunc.py
`- main.py
```

with the following content:

In `myfunc.py` there is

```py
def myverynicefunc():
    print('Hello, I am your very nice func :)')
```

in `script.py` there is

```py
import myfunc

def scriptfunc():
    print('I am the script function :)')

myfunc.myverynicefunc()
```

and in `main.py` there is

```py
from subdir.script import scriptfunc

scriptfunc()
```

If I go to the `subdir` directory and execute the script it works, I mean:

```
.../main_dir/subdir$ python3 script.py 
Hello, I am your very nice func :)
```

However if I try to execute the `main.py` script it fails:

```
.../main_dir$ python3 main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from subdir.script import scriptfunc
  File "/home/alf/Escritorio/main_dir/subdir/script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import myfunc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myfunc'
```

If I modify the content of `script.py` to

```py
from . import myfunc

def scriptfunc():
    print('I am the script function :)')

myfunc.myverynicefunc()
```

now the situation is the inverse, the `main.py` script works ok:

```
.../main_dir$ python3 main.py 
Hello, I am your very nice func :)
I am the script function :)
```

but the `script.py` script fails:

```
.../main_dir/subdir$ python3 script.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import myfunc
ImportError: cannot import name 'myfunc'
```

Is there a way to make both calls to `main.py` and to `script.py` to work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `script.py`-

```
import sys
current_path = sys.path[0]
if current_path.split('/')[-1] != 'subdir':
    sys.path.insert(0, current_path+'/subdir/')
    import myfunc
```

By this, if the current directory for python is the parent directory of the file, that is the `maindir`, it would change the path to directory and then import it.

With this, it should work in both scenarios. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, you were near. Your answer as it is didn't worked, but a little modification did indeed. I had to place this in ```script.py```   ```import sys
current_path = sys.path[0]
if current_path.split('/')[-1] != 'subdir':
 sys.path.insert(0, current_path+'/subdir/')
 from . import myfunc
else:
 import myfunc```

Comment: Although this worked, seems like an ugly solution (sorry). I will wait some time to see if some one provides a better answer. Else I will accept yours :). Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to add that, though I had that in mind. Sorry! :P

Comment: Yes, it's highly not recommended. It's just a hack around it. :)

Answer (score 0):

with the second scenario, you can do 
python3 -c "import subdir.script" in your main directory